# Auto-fill rows between two cells in iWork - Numbers (or MS Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, iwork-numbers

This is my table

```
...A............
1  1
2  
3  
4  
5  9
```

I know the minimum value (A1=1) and I know the maxiumum value (A5=9). Now I want to fill the rows in between with the numbers leading up to the maximum value.

So it looks like this:

```
...A............
1  1
2  3
3  5
4  7
5  9
```

How can I do this in iWork Numbers? (maybe its the same as in Excel?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this into cell A2 (this works for Excel 2007) and drag down:

`=A1+($A$5-$A$1)/(ROW($A$5)-ROW($A$1))`

Basically, this figures out how many rows between your first and last, then what the difference is between the two values, then adds that value-per-cell calculation to the preceding cell.

Answer (score 5):

In Excel, select the range that includes your starting and ending cells. In the Home ribbon, in the Editing section, click Fill, select Series, click OK and you're done.

Comment: Thanks, I actually dont have Excel so I cant test it but Im sure it works :)

Comment: +1 - This is good to know if you are using just Excel!

Comment: @mdc: Well, your title and one of your tags say "Excel".

Comment: Thats because there could be a solution that works in both Numbers and Excel (like the one JNK provided).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my [VBA answer](https://superuser.com/questions/175309/averages-spread-out-over-several-fields-in-excel/175328#175328), that will be easy to modify to do what you want.